# protractor cannot focus element

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Im new to protractor and I have tried to remove custom directive(input-date) from DOM so that I can mock my ng-model

my HTML

```
<input type="text" name="rptdate" input-date placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" data-ng-model="newPatReports.reportDate" />
```

Js

```
var remove_inputDate = element(by.name("rptdate"));
        browser.executeScript('arguments[0].removeAttribute("input-date");', remove_inputDate.getWebElement());
```

Now Im actually tring to insert seperate value for my ng-model, Im getting error stating "cannot focus element", Im not able to insert value...What could the problem....?

Any help is much appreciated........Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you note on which line are you getting the "Cannot focus" error? Also, having a complete test you execute would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe the error is on the line posted in the question. Commenting out that part of the HTML run the test to a pass.

Comment: I'm not so great at html, but is it supposed to have the `/` at the end of it? And if you're using it as a directive, shouldn't it be like `<input-date name="rptdate" ng-model="newPatReports.reportDate"></input-date>`? I'm not sure that this is a protractor-specific question.